# problem when publishing npm package with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package

so i recentely published a package with ts i set the type to **module** in the **package.json** to use import/export this is my tsconfig options

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "EsNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include": ["./" , "./src"]
}
```

then i installed it localy test it
when i  used it i got autocomplete which is greet but it gives me this error when it try to run it

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\Anas\Desktop\Programming\packages\Test\node_modules\pkg\' imported from C:\Users\Anas\Desktop\Programming\packages\Test\index.js
←[90m    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)←[39m
←[90m    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:235:9)←[39m
←[90m    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:14)←[39m
←[90m    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)←[39m
←[90m    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)←[39m
←[90m    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)←[39m
←[90m    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)←[39m
←[90m    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)←[39m
←[90m    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)←[39m
←[90m    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

in the **tsconfig** i changed the module to NodeNext and the moduleResolution to nodenext but it didn't fix any thing

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "EsNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "removeComments": true
    },
    "include": ["./" , "./src"]
}
```

#### How To Fix This Please Help

Comment: `"include": ["./" , "./src"]` doesn't make sence as it's equivalent to `"include": ["./"]` and thus to no `include` key at all

Comment: You need to `main: "dist/index.js"` in `package.json`, see docs

Comment: (and `types: "dist/index.d.ts"` if you `declarations: true`)

Comment: Actually if you don't care about non-TS package users you don't really have to compile it and may just `files: ["src"], main: "src/index.ts"` so user will import the package as TS file